# Box2D how to implement a camera?

Tags: java, box2d

By now i have this Camera class.

```
package GameObjects;


import main.Main;

import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
public class Camera {

public int x;
public int y;
public int sx;
public int sy;

public static final float PIXEL_TO_METER = 50f;

private float yFlip = -1.0f;

public Camera()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    sx = x + Main.APPWIDTH;
    sy = y + Main.APPHEIGHT;
}

public Camera(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    sx = x + Main.APPWIDTH;
    sy = y + Main.APPHEIGHT;
}

public void update()
{
    sx = x + Main.APPWIDTH;
    sy = y + Main.APPHEIGHT;
}

public void moveCam(int mx, int my)
{

    if(mx >= 0 && mx <= 80)
    {
        this.x -= 2;
    } else if(mx <= Main.APPWIDTH && mx >= Main.APPWIDTH - 80)
    {
        this.x += 2;
    }

    if(my >= 0 && my <= 80)
    {
        this.y += 2;
    } 
    else if(my <= Main.APPHEIGHT && my >= Main.APPHEIGHT - 80)
    {
        this.y -= 2;
    }
    this.update();
}

public float meterToPixel(float meter)
{
    return meter * PIXEL_TO_METER;
}

public float pixelToMeter(float pixel)
{
    return pixel / PIXEL_TO_METER;
}

public Vec2 screenToWorld(Vec2 screenV) {
    return new Vec2(screenV.x + this.x, yFlip
            * screenV.y + this.y);
}

public Vec2 worldToScreen(Vec2 worldV) {
    return new Vec2(worldV.x - this.x, yFlip
            * worldV.y - this.y);
}
```

}

I need to know how to modify the screenToWorld and worldToScreen functions to include the PIXEL_TO_METER scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this myself. Here is what everyone who has the same problem should do:

```
public Vec2 screenToWorld(Vec2 screenV) {
    return new Vec2( this.x + screenV.x / PIXEL_TO_METER, yFlip
            * (screenV.y / PIXEL_TO_METER + this.y));
}

public Vec2 worldToScreen(Vec2 worldV) {
    return new Vec2((worldV.x - this.x) * PIXEL_TO_METER, (yFlip
            * worldV.y - this.y) * PIXEL_TO_METER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Romeo. this is very helpful.
can you tell me the meaning of the variable "yFlip"?
i don't understand why it's declared as float.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. You will understand from here: http://www.shiffman.net/itp/classes/nature/box2d_2010/worlds.jpg . As you can see in the Box2D world y is incremented by going up. Well, in the screen world the y is incremented by going down. So you need to transform that value using the yFlip and is declared by float because i need to  multiply it to another float value without doing any conversion.